# Dropdown Semantic-UI

Tags: jquery, select, dropdown, semantic-ui

I use *Semantic-ui* to build user interface.

But I faced an issue: is it possible to do that dropdown will be added not to the element itself, but to the *body*?
Because now it looks as follows:
[image: As you can see my table has scroll and select]

I can't find necessary information in documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you can't get rid of the `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` property of the container that the dropdown is in. I think that the only solution to your problem would be to change the `direction` setting of the dropdown to `'upwards'` since there seems to be space above it inside its container:

```
$('.ui.dropdown')
  .dropdown({
    direction: 'upward'
  })
;
```

[JSFiddle I made trying to solve this.](https://jsfiddle.net/jgjp/864spbk1/2/)

edit: either that or use a [modal](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html) instead of dropdown